# Check if TimePicker time is less than current time

Tags: android, date, calendar, android-timepicker

I'm trying to set time from a `TimePicker`dialog in a `TextView` after checking if the set time is past the current time. I take the time that is selected from the `TimePicker` in a string `s` and parsed it in `(hh:mm)` format.I used `SimpleDateFormat.parse("hh:mm")` but it compares the time in the year 1970 and today's date and time.

So I tried `SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss.SSS").parse(s);` along with the date,month and year but it is giving me `ParseException`. I use the `before()` to check if the time selected is before the current time. But I should parse the time that is set along with date and time first to use the method. How to check if the time set in `TimePicker` is the less than current time.

This is what I tried:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        String s = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + "-" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + String.valueOf((datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + datetime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        try {
            Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss.SSS").parse(s);
            Date date = c.getTime();
            if (d.before(c.getTime())) {
                DateTimePicker.setBooleanDateCheckForTimePicker(false);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter valid time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
            am_pm = "AM";
        else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
            am_pm = "PM";

        String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ? "12" : datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "";
        boolean b = new DateTimePicker().booleanDateCheckForTimePicker;
        if (new DateTimePicker().booleanDateCheckForTimePicker) {
            timePicker.setText(strHrsToShow + ":" + datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + am_pm);
        }


        //timePicker.setText(hourOfDay + " "+minute);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your quesition is not clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just compare timestamp.

```
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        if(datetime.getTimeInMillis() > c.getTimeInMillis()){
//            it's after current
        }else{
//            it's before current'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing the comparison using Date you can just check it manually like this:

```
var isBefore=false;

if(hourOfDay < datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
  isBefore=true;
else if(hourOfDay == datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)){
  if(minute < datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    isBefore=true;
}
```